# trasform 137.5 in 1375

Tags: sql

I have do select that contains a sum, I would like to convert the result (decimal) of the sum in integer result.
example:
137.5 in 1375

that any amount that I extract

it's possible?

Comment: Always tag your rdbms. While this question is very generic but it is always helps to know more details

Answer (score 1):

You can simply multiply it by `10` and cast it as `int`

If its SQL Server then it would be like

```
select cast((137.5*10.0) as int)
```

In general you can use it like

```
select cast((result*10) as int)
```

Note that I have assumed that the result has only one place of decimal.

Comment: MIght need to use `10.0` instead of `10`. Otherwise it might implicitly cast 137.5 to an int and make the sum 137*10.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:- Nice pick. Thanks for pointing it. Updated that!

Comment: if I have one, multiplying it by 10 and 10 I get no good if I get 10 to 137.5 moltiplicanto 1,375 and not good because it is added to the point, I want to exclude eventauli points, the values I get the sum should be no comma and points.
example:

1,375 should be 1,375
1 must remain 1
10 should be 10
10.10 must be 1010

so I have to add the values to the right and the left of the decimal point getting an integer.

Comment: @Pieppolo:- Then you can try this one as others have answered! `SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(result AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT)`

Comment: if i try this:SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(result AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT) i get  117500000 i don't want the zeros

Comment: is possible edit only values with comma removing the zeros that it adds

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to `CAST` it to `VARCHAR`, remove the `.` and then cast it back to an `int`

```
DECLARE @Value NUMERIC(18,3) = 15.435
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@Value AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT)
```

Comment: if I have one, multiplying it by 10 and 10 I get no good if I get 10 to 137.5 moltiplicanto 1,375 and not good because it is added to the point, I want to exclude eventauli points, the values I get the sum should be no comma and points.
example:

1,375 should be 1,375
1 must remain 1
10 should be 10
10.10 must be 1010

so I have to add the values to the right and the left of the decimal point getting an integer.

Comment: which database are you using? Did you try to cast this value into varchar and replace `.` and then cast it back to int? what is the type for this column which stores `137.5 `. unless we get more details we may not be able to help you

Comment: database is: db2 iseries

Comment: database is: db2 iseries  ; column decimal(31,6) ; i used replace, but it add zeros , example:

Comment: database is: db2 iseries ; column decimal(31,6) ; i used replace, but it add zeros , example: the sum i get result 117,5 with replace(sum(b.bhnfc),'.','')  get this:  117500000

Comment: if i try: CAST(REPLACE(CAST(sum(b.bhnfc) AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT) get this 117500000 , 1175 is ok, but the zeros are not good.

Comment: the field where it do the sum is of type NUMERIC (15,6)

Comment: i have know, if try this CAST(REPLACE(CAST(sum(b.bhnfc) AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT)  i get this: 117500000 because the fiel is of type NUMERIC(15,6) IT ADD SIX ZEROS AND HENCE I GET THIS RESULT 1175000000

Comment: Try casting it to float first and then to char and then to int. `CAST(REPLACE(CAST(CAST(sum(b.bhnfc) AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(100)),'.','') AS INT)`